# Pyspark- calculate percentage of the item appear in the customer transition data

Tags: python, pyspark

My dataset looks like this (this table is the transaction table for the customers(it record each transaction that customers made), List column contains the product that customer purchase in one transaction, I want to find for each customer, what is the percentage of the  combo product 'b' and 'c' that they purchased

```
|ID     |AMOUNT |     List     |
|:------|:-----:|-------------:|
|    123|    1  |['a','b','c'] |
|    123|    3  |['a','b','c'] |
|    123|    4  |['b','c']     |
|    123|    4  |['a']         |
|    456|    5  |['a','b','c'] |
|    456|    6  |['b']         |
```

So the ideal output table I would like to get using pyspark looks like this below

```
|customer |Amount   | product 'b' and 'c' percentage |
|123      |[1,3,4,4]|   0.75                         |
|456      |[5,6]    |   0.5                          |
```

Comment: This result is quite easy to obtain :)

Comment: Please add your expected result, as you seem to have dropped it from the post.

Comment: Please also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I am still new to this stackflow. this is just part of the my code. I am using pyspark and got stuck on this step and run out of the thoughts. i know i would probably need count function to get the percentage. any advice would be really helpful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to group by the `ID` and then count the number of aggregated rows twice:

- all rows and
- rows where `List` contains the two elements `b` and `c` using [array_intersect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect.html)

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy('ID') \
    .agg(
        F.count('AMOUNT').alias('cnt'), 
        F.count(F.when(F.size(F.array_intersect('List', F.array(F.lit('b'),F.lit('c')))) >= 2 ,
            F.col('AMOUNT'))).alias('cnt_bc')
        )\
    .withColumn('result', F.col('cnt_bc') / F.col('cnt')) \
    .show()
```

prints

```
+---+---+------+------+
| ID|cnt|cnt_bc|result|
+---+---+------+------+
|123|  4|     3|  0.75|
|456|  2|     1|   0.5|
+---+---+------+------+
```